# Magento: adding external jQuery files

Tags: jquery, magento

I'd like to know how to add external jQuery files to magento (on every page).
And what is the best practice to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this.
on the frontend (a default theme) do the modification for " app / design / frontend / default / default / layout / page.xml and then add this :

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.min.js</script></action> to block with name “head” .
```

And on the backend (a default theme) do the modification for " modify app / design / adminhtml / default / default / layout / main.xml. :

Thats how javascript files will be included in every page header.
And here is a link to which you can refer and learn more.
http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/using-jquery-magento " to learn more.

here is how you gotta write the " noConflict " .

```
<default>
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Good luck

Comment: okay so i have a theme that already uses jQuery files. 
So i think that i can safely assume that `jQuery.noConflict()` method would have been already applied, right?
So will just adding jQuerry files to the page.xml will do the trick?

Comment: You gotta write the " noConflict " too . I'd just add it to my codes.

Comment: I suggest you to read this too . http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/using-jquery-magento

Comment: 1) Create & use *local.xml* for layout modifications; do not modify *page.xml*. 2) Do not hardcode the protocol or you will get insecure content warnings on checkout.

Comment: @benmarks okay benmarks thanks. But how will i include the new page.xml file in my magento pages? and where should i keep it?(which directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in Page.xml. You can find it in the layout folder of your template. In order to avoid conflicts with other libraries, you should  call jQuery.noConflict()